# class xx not found in relational query

Tags: laravel, laravel-6.2

I have problem with my Laravel 6.6.2 !!

When I want to access sub table! sometimes I got bellow error

> Class 'App\product' not found

model :

```
public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\product', 'id', 'product_id');
    }
```

controller

```
$active_buying_log = ProductBuyingLog::first();
dd($active_buying_log->product);
```

But every things works fine when I change controller code like bellow code.

```
$active_buying_log = ProductBuyingLog::first();
$variable = Product::first();
dd($active_buying_log->product);
```

my php version : 7.2

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model name is in capital(`Product`) so use capital. you used small later in `ProductBuyingLog` model. Replace it in capital your error will be gone.

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Product', 'id', 'product_id');
```

In addition, You passed **wrong place of parameter**. the first one should be `foreign_key` and second one will be `primary_key`

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Product', 'product_id', 'id');
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh my God.

Comment: my co-worker has work on crazy Windows! and I have Ubuntu. Thanks Dilip

Comment: and the problem was about lower and capital case.